# Unable to manage mobile account settings

Tags: macos, network-user, mobile-device-management

I'm trying to manage my mobile account settings after migrating my local account to a network account.

The problem is that the settings button is greyed out.

[image]

How can I change this in order to get my local account syncing with my home server?

*note: the lock icon is "locked" in the screenshot, however even unlocked the settings button is still grey*

Answer (score 2):

This is something you'll have to change in Workgroup Manager on your home server (assuming you're using Mac OS X Server).

What you'll need to do is:

1. Open **Workgroup Manager** from `/Applications/Server`
2. **Authenticate** as a server administrator
3. Find your user account and go to the **Preferences** tab
4. Go to **Mobility**
5. Change all the managed preferences from Once or Always to **Never**:

[image]

**Log out** and log back in on your client computer and you should be good to go!

Comment: Is this different than the "mobility" stuff that's found in Profile Manager?

Comment: According to [another stack exchange answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29134/lion-server-is-mobility-in-workgroup-manager-related-to-profile-manager-in-the), they're different tools to do the same thing. I've always used Workgroup Manager, however.

Comment: So I took a look, and I discovered that all those settings were already as you described. What I didn't have was the `afp://myserver/Users` in the OD directory settings.

Comment: http://www.themacosxserveradmin.com/2011/02/different-types-of-open-directory-users.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into active directory (Windows 2008 R2) and go to the user's properties. From there, Profile Tab, then the "connect" radio button under "Home folder" has to have any drive letter selected, and a UNC path the the location that the users home folder will reside.